# Dictionary in C++ using a Map with no values, only keys

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm implementing some sort of lookup for words in c++, and while the code for implementing a map is there, I wanna make sure if it works that using a map with keys and values as std::string, and using only keys as lookups without a value to return.

```
    std::vector< std::string> DictionLines;
    Reader DictionReader(Dictionary);
    DictionLines = DictionReader.getLines();
    std::map<std::string, std::string> DictionaryM;

    for (int t = 0; t < DictionLines.size(); ++t) {
        DictionaryM.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(DictionLines.at(t), DictionLines.at(t)));
    }
```

This code takes in the 349900 words in a Dictionary.txt file, and stores them in the map. Each line of the dictionary is just the word to lookup; no definition or any value to associate. Which is why I think just storing a pair of the same key and value in the map is ok, and using find and first/second would also be fine? Please confirm.

Comment: You... do know about std::set right?

Comment: @Ludwik Apparently he doesn't and that's why he asked. Perfectly valid question imho.

Comment: Wait but the time to lookup for an element in `set` is `O(logN)` while in HashMap is `O(1)`. So it's not the same. [Looked up more into it: `unordered_sets` have a search time complexity of `O(1)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you want [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). It is like a map where only keys matter and you never care or use the value. To look in a dictionary represented as a `std::set<std::string>` for some word after a given prefix, consider [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound)

You should look more into C++ standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). There are not that much choice, and you should somehow know all of them (and choose or combine the right containers for the job)

Comment: In other words, the values **are** the keys.

Comment: I know I marked this as an answer but plz help again.

I sought tree structure because of speed O(log n) when searching for a specific key. However, now that I implemented this as a set and thought of my next step, I realize I don't search for keys specifically; I look through the dictionary for words that have the same length as my "key". Wouldn't this ultimately return to being O(n) time if I linearly iterate through the set like this? This is some sort of Spell Checker that I'm implementing.

Comment: @Kthieu Sounds like you want a map, where keys are lengths, and values are containers with words of that length (could be simple list, could be set, could be a map), or just `std::multimap`. Also note that for lookup, *O(log n)* you mention is *slow*, not fast. Unordered maps and sets (implemented with hash tables, and often called hashes or hashmaps, in C++ `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`) achieve *O(n)* lookup and (amortized) insertion times. TL;DR Know your containers, as also said in this answer!