# Is it worth having a redundant "support container"?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, containers, redundancy

I have an `std::vector` (unordered), and on its specific elements (by their index) I have to call a method every cycle in an **infinite loop**.

But sometimes (maybe every 30.000th cycle) I want to **search in them** by the elements' member. (`std::string`)

Should I create an **unordered_map** to fasten up this search, or it doesn't worth the redundancy?

*(The elements after adding them to the container, aren't removed, aren't moved, etc, they are only used.)*

- So when I add an element to the vector, I also add a `pair<std::string, integer>` to an unordered map.

  - This way when I search by its "name" I can get its index fast
  - Instead of slowly going through the vector and comparing strings.
  - *(I think that unordered_map's `at()` is faster than lots of string comparing. Correct me If I'm wrong.)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046197/dictionary-in-c-using-a-map-with-no-values-only-keys

Comment: Could you explain why do you recommend using a set?

Comment: Did you try both approaches and compared them? Yes -> there you go, that's the correct answer for your problem. No -> why not? You can only know for sure if you measure it. Theoretical asymptotic run time is _not_ a  perfect predictor of actual performance.

Comment: I hoped that someone already measured this, and I don't have to implement them both. But yeah, if nobody knows the answer then I should do it on my own :D

Comment: @Tudvari Well it's just fairly unlikely that someone actually had this exact problem to solve. It depends on so many factors (amount of data, memory layout, order of accesses, write / read ratio, etc.). A good rule of thumb is "use vector", as this data structure is blazingly fast in many situations, even if other data structures should beat it theoretically. But of course vector is not perfect every time. Try to write your code in a way that you can easily swap out data types to make experimenting with types a more efficient task. But in the end, you have to measure.

Comment: It significantly depends on amount of data you have.

Comment: The way you answer this question is to write code that works, benchmark it with real data, then modify it with your proposed "optimization" and benchmark it again with real data. Which one is faster? Is the performance differential worth it? Guessing is basically just a waste of time.

Comment: I can only tell you that your approach is not insane or unreasonable. _But_ you should determine whether you really need it, first. Only you can determine that.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm trying to change my mindset and only think about "little optimization" at the end.